# addEventListener inside if statement wont work for toggle click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

kindly asking a question,
my goal is 
click `div class="head"` 
show or hide `div class="toggle"`  
or click outside div to hide `div class="toggle"`

after adding addEventListner inside if statement , it just run a single click then doesn't toggle anymore
How to fix that, Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.head', function(elem) { // click div with class = head
    var toggle = elem.target.getElementsByClassName('toggle')[0]
    if (toggle.style.display = "none") {
      toggle.style.display = "";

      document.addEventListener('click', function() {
        toggle.style.display = "none";
      })
    } else {
      toggle.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="head">expand
    <div class="toggle" style="display:none;">
      <p>number 1</p>
      <p>number 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (toggle.style.display = "none")` *probably* wanted `if (toggle.style.display === "none")`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for comment , it's not working either == or ===

Comment: No, that's just the first issue.  When you click on head, you add a another handler that hides the toggle on *every click* - so when you click to show, it gets shown, but then the other handler also fires and it gets immediately hidden.  Add some `console.log("step 1")` (etc) liberally through your code so you can see what's going on.  You probably want the inner/close-when-clicking-outside event to be a one-off, as you're using jquery, you can do this with [.one()](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for the explanation and solution , i understood now how this script execute one to another, it is working now by using ```one()```

Comment: @freedomn-m After i understand your explanation , i found multiple solution by using  ```once: true,``` or use ```callback``` with ````removeEventListener```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the script by using `once:true;` or `one()` that recommended by @freedomn-m 
Thank you guys for all the comments and answers

pure js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.head', function(elem) { // click div with class = head
    var toggle = elem.target.getElementsByClassName('toggle')[0]
    if (toggle.style.display == "none") {
      toggle.style.display = "";
      
        document.addEventListener('click',function(){
            toggle.style.display = "none";
        }, {
        once: true,
        });
    } else {
      toggle.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
})
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.head', function(elem) { // click div with class = head
    var toggle = elem.target.getElementsByClassName('toggle')[0]
    if (toggle.style.display == "none") {
      toggle.style.display = "";
      
        $(document).one('click',function(){
          toggle.style.display = "none";  
        })
        
    } else {
      toggle.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0];
  
  document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (toggle.style.display !== "none") {
      toggle.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.head', function(elem) { // click div with class = head      
    if (toggle.style.display = "none") {
      toggle.style.display = "";
    } else {
      toggle.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="head">expand
    <div class="toggle" style="display:none;">
      <p>number 1</p>
      <p>number 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer , it is not working, click ```div class="head"``` 2nd time wont hide , only click ```document```to hide is working